# Restricting JavaFX Window Resizing to Minimum Size of the Root

Tags: javafx, resize, bind

How to stop the JavaFx stage from shrinking beneath the min size of the root node?

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of your stage, Like this:

```
stage.setSize(height, width);
```